# sum of binomial coefficients ratio

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I know that $ {n \choose 0.5 \cdot n}$ is the largest binomial coefficient. Yet, I'm not sure if the sum of other coefficient is larger. That is, consider the following expression $ x= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{0.5 \cdot n - 1} {n \choose k}\right) - {n \choose 0.5 \cdot n}$

Is $x\geq 0$. Or even, is $x = \Omega(n^2)$?

Comment: The sum is much larger. Inspect the Wallis formula to find out the ratio $2^{2n}\over {2n\choose n.}$

Answer (score 0):

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac n 2-1}\binom{n}{k}=2^n-\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$\Delta_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac n 2-1}\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}=2^{n-1} \left(1-\frac{3 \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\right)$$ If $n$ is large
$$\Delta_n=2^{n-1}\Bigg[1-3 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}
  +O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right) \Bigg]$$